# Why can't service host from Unity.Wcf resolve service's instance correctly?

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container, .net-4.6

I have a unity container:

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
```

configured as follows:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IExampleDomainService, ExampleDomainService>();

unityContainer.RegisterType<IExampleWebService, ExampleWebService>();
```

`ExampleWebService` type and its constructor look as follows:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ExampleWebService
{
    public ExampleWebService(IExampleDomainService exampleDomainService)
    {
        this.exampleDomainService = exampleDomainService;
    }

// ...
```

and `ExampleDomainService` has no constructor defined (the problem is the same when I explicitly define a parameterless constructor for this type).

Next, as explained in Unity.Wcf's [documentation](http://unitywcf.codeplex.com/):

> If you are hosting your WCF service within a Windows Service using a `ServiceHost`, replace the `ServiceHost` instance with the custom `Unity.Wcf.UnityServiceHost`. You will find that the `UnityServiceHost` takes in a Unity container as its first parameter but is otherwise identical to the default `ServiceHost`.

I do the following:

```
 var host = new UnityServiceHost(unityContainer, typeof(ExampleWebService), baseAddress);
```

This however throws `System.InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.

Looking at [`UnityServiceHost` implementation at GitHub](https://github.com/gruan01/Unity.WCF.4/blob/master/UnityServiceHost.cs) it passes given `serviceType` (`typeof(ExampleWebService)` in this case) directly to WCF's native `ServiceHost`:

```
public sealed class UnityServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public UnityServiceHost(IUnityContainer container, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
      : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
             ???????????
```

which obviously crashes, as `ServiceHost` does not know anything about Unity and its container and cannot cope when parameterless constructor is missing.

Is Unity.Wcf completely broken for non-WAS/non-IIS hosting or (I hope) I am  doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry, I can not tell you why you have your exception, but I hope to help you.

1. `ServiceHost` does not need to know anything about Unity. DI done via
   implementing [`IInstanceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and registering it for each
   service behavior
2. It just work for me, here is very basic application
   which work correctly, maybe you can find what's the problem on your
   side

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var container = new UnityContainer();
           container.RegisterType<IDependency, Dependency>();
           container.RegisterType<IHelloWorldService, HelloWorldService>();
           Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");
           using (ServiceHost host = new UnityServiceHost(container, typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
           {
               ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
               smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
               smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
               host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

               host.Open();

               Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
               Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
               Console.ReadLine();

               host.Close();
           }
       }
   }

   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IHelloWorldService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       string SayHello(string name);
   }

   public interface IDependency
   {

   }

   public class Dependency : IDependency { }

   public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
   {
       private readonly IDependency _dependency;

       public HelloWorldService(IDependency dependency)
       {
           _dependency = dependency;
       }

       public string SayHello(string name)
       {
           return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
       }
   }
   ```
3. WCF does not call `InstanceProvider` if `InstanceContextMode.Single` used. That's why Unity.WCF does not work with it. Detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453261/unity-wcf-and-instancecontextmode-single).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this out. Could you please indicate which version of Unity.Wcf are you using?

Comment: @BartoszKP I was testing with https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityWCF/2.0.5849.32640 , but I think it's very similar to one you have

Comment: Side note: There seems to be an older version on NuGet called Unity.Wcf (note the dot) - this is the one I was using. I've switched to your version, and I'll try to find out the difference between your implementation and mine.

Comment: It works, thanks! The difference was I had a leftover from an initial draft version of my service: `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ...`. This setting somehow makes impossible to resolve service's instance. Perhaps you could comment on that on your answer so it will be helpful for other people (I've added this detail into my question). I still don't understand exactly why does it cause an exception, however I don't need single instance mode so the problem is solved in my case - thanks again :)

Comment: @BartoszKP regarding `Unity.Wcf` it's original package, but it does not support Unity 4.0+

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, and explains it all. The third point should be the first (if not the only one) of this answer, as this is exactly the core of the issue.

Comment: Also, I think this makes my question a duplicate :)