# Unity.WCF Asking for default constructor

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

Implementing Unity.WCF as seen here: https://unitywcf.codeplex.com/

When I host the service whilst using fileless activation it is still asking me for a default constructor, rather than resolve the Service via unity, I'm unsure what I have missed.

WCFServiceFactory:

```
public class WcfServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
{
protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
{
        container.RegisterType<IPollerSVC, ProductionHostSVC>()
                 .RegisterType<PeriodicTaskFactory>()
                 .RegisterType<CancellationTokenSource>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType<IProcessor, ThirdPartyProcessor>();      
}
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="IISHostThirdParty.WcfServiceFactory" relativeAddress="./ProductionHost.svc" service="Service.Common.ProductionHostSVC"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Service:

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Services/IPollerService")]
    public interface IPollerSVC
    {
        Task PollingTask { get; }

    }

[ServiceBehavior(Name = "Services.SL.ThirdParty.ServiceHost", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = true)]

public class ProductionHostSVC : IPollerSVC
{
    public ProductionHostSVC(IProcessor processor,
                             PeriodicTaskFactory taskFactory,
                             CancellationTokenSource ctks)
    {
        _ctks = ctks;

    }

    public Task PollingTask { get; }
}
```

Comment: This is a stretch, but you are registering the service with the container before some of its dependencies. Have you tried changing the registration order around so `.RegisterType<IPollerSVC, ProductionHostSVC>()` is last in `ConfigureContainer`.

Comment: I've just had a look and this doesn't work, nice idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old but still useful answer [is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453261/unity-wcf-and-instancecontextmode-single)

In short: WCF does not call `InstanceProvider` if `InstanceContextMode.Single` is used. So Unity.WCF can't be used to instantiate a service.